# Calculate average of 3 latest values in database

Tags: sql

I have table REG, i want to calc average from 3 latest field(`mood`) value. i use this sql, but this is false.

```
select AVG(mood) AS sent from reg ORDER BY mood DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using and what version?

Comment: Is the table `mood`, or the column? Is the table name `reg`? Also, can you describe what happens when you run this query?

Comment: sorry for typo, mood is field, and reg is table

Comment: the table seems to be "reg" and why would you sort by "mood" instead of some id or timestamp? how do you evaluate "it is false"? whats the output and what would you have expected?

Answer (score 1):

Try preselecting the values that you want in a subquery, and then averaging them (assuming that you are using a DBMS that employes the `Limit` keyword):

```
Select Avg(tmp.Mood)
From (Select Mood From reg order by CreateDate ASC Limit 3) as tmp
```